# Why doesn't my batch file execute automatically despite being placed in "Startup" folder?

Tags: batch-file

This must sound too naive because I am not a programmer. I need help with a batch file execution.

There are two user accounts on my Windows XP enabled PC and one of these accounts is used by my brother. Sometimes I need to leave messages for him to read as a reminder of something, for example, to back up his personal folders when he logs in next time.

So, I created a simple batch file with the following code:

```
@echo off  
msg * It's time to backup your folders!
```

When executed by double clicking, the file works fine and shows the expected message. I placed a copy of the batch file in "C:\Documents and Settings\Brother\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" but couldn't make it execute automatically when my brother logged in.

Could somebody please show me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://superuser.com/a/181845/106832) answer on Superuser, the startup folders for XP are actually in

```
%AllUsersProfile%\Start Menu\Startup
%UserProfile%\Start Menu\Startup
```

So the Programs\Startup may be used for something else.

Comment: I can't find either of the directories you have mentioned. 'Start Menu' __is__ found under 'Programs'.

Comment: on XP it use to be `\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 10, there are 2 things that may be doing this:

1. - Your file needs Administrator privileges (When i copy any file to startup with Admin privileges it will not work). - My experience
2. - When you boot your computer wait a bit (30 - 50 seconds) to load all files make sure to don't do anything.

This is my experience in Windows 10 please correct me if im wrong in anything